# How to update the 20 different cloudfront distributions using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have 20 cloudfront-distribution created in aws account. All are configured with originsslprotocl:SSLv3. If i use below command i need to edit 20 json files to disable/remove "SSLv3",can you please share your inputs to figure out the issue using cli.

"aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config  file://secure-ssl.json --if-match E1FDVLLC5LJOKG"

Steps i followed to disable/remove Originsslprotocol:SSLv3

1)"aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config  file://secure-ssl.json --if-match E1FDVLLC5LJOKG"
2)aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id  E29BDBENPXM1VE
3) Stored step2 output in secure-ssl.json and removed Etg,distribution parameters,originprotocol:SSLv3 value from json file
4)aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config  file://secure-ssl.json --if-match E1FDVLLC5LJOKG

{

```
    "Comment": "", 
    "CacheBehaviors": {
        "Quantity": 0
    }, 
    "IsIPV6Enabled": true, 
    "Logging": {
        "Bucket": "", 
        "Prefix": "", 
        "Enabled": false, 
        "IncludeCookies": false
    }, 
    "WebACLId": "", 
    "Origins": {
        "Items": [
            {
                "OriginPath": "", 
                "CustomOriginConfig": {
                    "OriginSslProtocols": {
                        "Items": [
                            "TLSv1.1", 
                            "TLSv1.2"
                        ], 
                        "Quantity": 2
                    }, 
                    "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only", 
                    "OriginReadTimeout": 30, 
                    "HTTPPort": 80, 
                    "HTTPSPort": 443, 
                    "OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
                }, 
                "CustomHeaders": {
                    "Quantity": 0
                }, 
                "Id": "ELB-cicdpipeline-646360150", 
                "DomainName": "cicdpipeline-646360150.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com"
            }
        ], 
        "Quantity": 1
    }, 
    "DefaultRootObject": "", 
    "PriceClass": "PriceClass_All", 
    "Enabled": true, 
    "DefaultCacheBehavior": {
        "FieldLevelEncryptionId": "", 
        "TrustedSigners": {
            "Enabled": false, 
            "Quantity": 0
        }, 
        "LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
            "Quantity": 0
        }, 
        "TargetOriginId": "ELB-cicdpipeline-646360150", 
        "ViewerProtocolPolicy": "allow-all", 
        "ForwardedValues": {
            "Headers": {
                "Quantity": 0
            }, 
            "Cookies": {
                "Forward": "none"
            }, 
            "QueryStringCacheKeys": {
                "Quantity": 0
            }, 
            "QueryString": false
        }, 
        "MaxTTL": 31536000, 
        "SmoothStreaming": false, 
        "DefaultTTL": 86400, 
        "AllowedMethods": {
            "Items": [
                "HEAD", 
                "GET"
            ], 
            "CachedMethods": {
                "Items": [
                    "HEAD", 
                    "GET"
                ], 
                "Quantity": 2
            }, 
            "Quantity": 2
        }, 
        "MinTTL": 0, 
        "Compress": false
    }, 
    "CallerReference": "1562748965921", 
    "ViewerCertificate": {
        "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": true, 
        "MinimumProtocolVersion": "TLSv1", 
        "CertificateSource": "cloudfront"
    }, 
    "CustomErrorResponses": {
        "Quantity": 0
    }, 
    "OriginGroups": {
        "Quantity": 0
    }, 
    "HttpVersion": "http1.1", 
    "Restrictions": {
        "GeoRestriction": {
            "RestrictionType": "none", 
            "Quantity": 0
        }
    }, 
    "Aliases": {
        "Quantity": 0
    }
}
```

}

It takes at least 10-15 mins to modify one distribution using above method.

1)Is there any method/cli command just to update/modify originsslprotocol
2) What is the reason for removing Etag when you are updating distribution?

Comment: can anyone please help me on this

Comment: There is not specific call to just update originsslprotocol, whenever you want to make any change in CloudFront, it's an updatedistribution call and you need to pass the change parameter. 2) What is the reason for removing Etag when you are updating distribution? --> etag is a kind of checksum calculated based on the previous config, if you're going to change anything in config, the checksum changes and you get new etag, you can compare it as etag in a http response.

Comment: Thank you james Dean. • “aws cloudfront update-distribution --id S11A16G5KZMEQD \
  --default-root-object index.html” ,this is to update default-root-object. Here  --distribution-config and json file is not passed to update the distribution. Similarly for above requirement is it possible to pass only –origin parameter